# How do I make my logo smaller without being blurry?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, resize, image-quality

I'd like to make this logo small enough to use on a Facebook profile photo which is 160 × 160 px. Will I have to redesign it to 160 × 160px?

[image: Asymmetric Solutions Logo]

Comment: If you scale that logo down you're going to have trouble with the legibility of the text. You may have to remove the text and show of the world, sword and feather as a stand alone smaller logo.

Comment: @Jack Remember to mark an answer as accepted if it helped! You can also post your own answer although I think [this one](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/42356/2857) explains what you did.

Answer (score 1):

While you're in the adobe illustrator file, select all the elements of the logo and up on the toolbar go `Object > Expand` or `Object > Expand Appearance` and have the options `Fill` and `Stroke` checked if available.

Once that's done you can resize it to what ever size you want without losing any quality. The stroke and fill ratios will stay the same. This technique is much faster than any other.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to redesign it. Just reduce to the size you need. As long as you are going smaller than the original size, you should not loose quality!

Comment: I ended making it work by deleting some details in the sword and making the strokes smaller in size. All I had to do with the quill was make the stroke smaller. I also reduced the size of the type. Thanks!